# Potential errata found: show the non locally connected points of a metric space form a discrete space, under a given new metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness, locally-connected

I am studying *Topology and Groupoids* by Ronald Brown, 3rd Edition. I believe I have spotted an errata in a given question, as I seem to have found a counterexample to what it wishes me to prove. I wish to know if I am correct or have misunderstood.

In the book, the following appears as exercise 3.3.8 (I have broken the question into parts of ease of reading):

> Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of a metric space $X$. We say $A$ is bounded if $sup\{d(x, y) : x,y\in A\}$ exists and then this number is called the **diameter** of $A$.

> Let $x, y\in X$. If there is a connected set containing $x, y$ of diameter $<1$, let $\sigma(x, y)$ be the infinum of the diameter of such sets. If no such set exists, let $\sigma(x, y) = 1$.

> (a) Prove that $(x, y)\mapsto \sigma(x, y)$ is a metric on $X$.

> (b) Let $L\subseteq X$ be the subset of $X$ of points at which $X$ is locally connected. Prove that $\sigma$ induces the discrete topology on $X\setminus L$ (if $X\setminus L \neq \emptyset$) and that $\sigma$ induces the same topology on $L$ as does $d$.

> (c) Prove that in $L$ the open ball for the metric $\sigma$ is connected if of radius $<1$.

I have proven (a), my problem is with (b). If I have not found an error, I think understanding why my counterexample does not work would be instructive:

Let $X$ be the "rational hair-comb" $(\mathbb{R}\times\{0\})\cup \bigcup_{z\in \mathbb{Q}} \{z\} \times [0, 1]$. This set is connected, but outside of the $x$ axis $X$ is not locally connected as any sufficiently small open ball away from the $x$ axis will intersect with countably many disconnected vertical lines. We then have $L = \mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$.

The question seems to indicate therefore that $X\setminus L$ together with $\sigma$ should have the discrete topology, but as far as I can tell for any $z_1 = (a, b), z_2 = (a, c)\in X$ on the same vertical line we will have $\sigma(z_1, z_2) = d(z_1, z_2) = |b - c|$ so long as $|b - c| < 1$.

Therefore every open ball of radius $\epsilon$ under $\sigma$ around $z_1$ will contain points distinct from $z_1$, so that $X\setminus L$ cannot have the discrete topology.

Is this correct, or is there something I am missing with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback from Nethesis and Lee Mosher.

After thinking about this for a while, it seems like your counterexample is valid. Perhaps one must require that $x$ and $y$ are contained in a connected *neighborhood*, rather than just a connected subset.

Comment: But there *are* connected sets on hairs: each subsegment of a hair is connected. I think this is the point of the OP's objections.

Comment: @LeeMosher thank you, that is correct

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the definition of locally connected, but I believe even with the obvious metric, $X$ is not locally connected. My understanding is that to be locally connected, one needs every neighbourhood of a point to contain a connected neighbourhood. The reason what you say does not imply local connectedness is that though a single hair is connected, no neighbourhood can contain only a single hair.

Comment: @Nethesis, ignore what I wrote, I was thinking of a different metric than what you have in mind, i.e. it wasn't so "obvious".

Comment: Only further point, for any future people stuck on this question, is that you need to define $\sigma (x, x) := 0$ in order for the first part to still work.